# How to fix broken XML generated by SOAP::Lite

Tags: perl, soap

currently I am experiencing with certain SOAP-based web services; and I want to use SOAP::Lite to communicate with these services.

In the first test, everything worked fine; until I had an ampersand (`&`) in my data.

When performing the request, I do this with the following snippet:

```
my $or_client = SOAP::Lite->new(
    proxy => '...',
    readable => 1,
    autotype => 0,
);
my $or_response = $or_client->call(
    'aMethod',
    SOAP::Data->name('company_name')->value('ACME'),
    ...
);
```

When I enable tracing (add the line `SOAP::Lite->import(trace => 'debug');`), I can see the following data sent to the server:

```
<soap:Envelope 
soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
...>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns:aMethod>
            <company_name>ACME</company_name>
            ...
        </ns:aMethod>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This works without any problems. But when the value for my data object contains special characters:

```
SOAP::Data->name("company_name")->value("ACME & Co.")
```

Then I get a 500 Internal Server error; with the faultstring "Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?) ..."

I inspected the XML sent to the SOAP service, and I noticed that my "&" in "ACME & Co" is not XML escaped in the right manner:

```
<company_name>ACME & Co.</company_name>
```

Is there any special option which I have to turn on; or do I have to do the XML escaping for myself before setting it in the `value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any special option which I have to turn on; or do I have to do the XML escaping for myself before setting it in the value?

You can do it like that:

```
SOAP::Data->name("company_name")->value(SOAP::Utils::encode_data("ACME & Co."))
```

Proof:

```
  DB<3> $m = SOAP::Data->name("company_name")->value(SOAP::Utils::encode_data("ACME & Co."));

  DB<6> use Data::Dumper

  DB<7> print Dumper $m
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_value' => [
                               'ACME &amp; Co.'
                             ],
                 '_attr' => {},
                 '_name' => 'company_name',
                 '_signature' => []
               }, 'SOAP::Data' );
```